# Assist with PHP method syntax

Tags: php

I hope this will be an easy question for somebody.  Here is the background:

I have the following code:

```
$conn=$this->conn1;

$fdata = $conn->parseFiller2( $record[ 'filler2' ] );
```

What I would like help with is simply not having to do the first line (set the $conn to be equal to $this->conn1)...

On the second line I am thinking that I should just use "$this->conn1" instead of "$conn"  but with the arrows and stuff I am just not sure how to code this properly.  So I am hoping someone can help with this...

All the best, Gerard

Comment: `$fdata = $this->conn1->parseFiller2( $record[ 'filler2' ] );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your current code does is that it creates a reference to `$this->conn1` and saves that in a variable called `$conn`. That is to say, `$conn` and `$this->conn1` now point to the same thing. You can simply replace `$conn` with `$this->conn1`:

```
// This line is no longer needed
// $conn=$this->conn1;

$fdata = $this->conn1->parseFiller2( $record[ 'filler2' ] );
```